# How to identify previous view controller in navigation stack

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have 2 seperate `navigationcontrollers`, one with `RootViewController` A and the other with `RootViewController` B.

I am able to push `ViewController` C onto either A or B's navigation stack.

Question: When I am in `ViewController` C, how can I find out if I am in the stack belonging to A or B?

Comment: Why not just create a previousViewController property on C that you set when you push C? Or give C the info it need from A or B when you push it?

Comment: @TerryWilcox , 'cos the relations could be very complicated nowadays

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You could use the `UINavigationController`'s `viewControllers` property:

> `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers`
>
> Discussion: The root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller

You could use that to test whether the root view controller (the one at array index 0) is view controller A or B.

Comment: How can I get this as a string in SWIFT.. (I'm new to swift)

Comment: @cyberboy just as easy: with `var viewControllers: [UIViewController]`

Comment: Previous view controller will be at `viewControllers.last`

Comment: @Burak `viewControllers.last` has current view controller, In order to get previous view controller one should use `viewControllers[viewControllers.count-2]`

Answer (score 105):

Here's the implementation of the accepted answer:

```
- (UIViewController *)backViewController
{
    NSInteger numberOfViewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count;

    if (numberOfViewControllers < 2)
        return nil;
    else
        return [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:numberOfViewControllers - 2];
}
```

Comment: I recommend adding this as a category on `UIViewController`

Answer (score 29):

```
- (UIViewController *)backViewController
{
    NSInteger myIndex = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self];

    if ( myIndex != 0 && myIndex != NSNotFound ) {
        return [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:myIndex-1];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

A more general implementation of the accepted answer:

```
- (UIViewController *)backViewController {
    NSArray * stack = self.navigationController.viewControllers;

    for (int i=stack.count-1; i > 0; --i)
        if (stack[i] == self)
            return stack[i-1];

    return nil;
}
```

This will return the correct "back view controller" regardless of where the current class is on the navigation stack.

Answer (score 9):

Swift implementation of [tjklemz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19371401/178280) code as an extension:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func backViewController() -> UIViewController? {        
        if let stack = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
            for(var i=stack.count-1;i>0;--i) {
                if(stack[i] == self) {
                    return stack[i-1]
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I've posted a modified version of this code that has Swift 3 support below as a new answer.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a modifed version of [Prabhu Beeman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33919438/1349789) Swift code that adapts it to support Swift 3:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func backViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        if let stack = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
            for i in (1..<stack.count).reverse() {
                if(stack[i] == self) {
                    return stack[i-1]
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: a couple of notes: reverse() now is reversed() and the self.navigationController?.viewControllers never contains the "self" view controller, so return stack.last should be enough

Answer (score 5):

As a `UINavigationController` extension:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func previousViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        guard viewControllers.count > 1 else {
            return nil
        }
        return viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Access the `n-2` element of the [`viewControllers`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW16) property to access the parent view controller.

Once you have that instance, you can check its type by logging what comes out of the [`NSStringFromClass()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromClass) function. Or you could keep some `static const` identifier string in controllers A and B, and a getter function that prints out the string.

Comment: any simple way of getting the current index of a view controller or shall I hardcode them depending on my hierarchy structure.

Answer (score 2):

Swift implementation of @tjklemz code:

```
var backViewController : UIViewController? {

        var stack = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array

        for (var i = stack.count-1 ; i > 0; --i) {
            if (stack[i] as UIViewController == self) {
                return stack[i-1] as? UIViewController
            }

        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: How can I get this as a string.. (I'm new to swift)

Comment: @cyberboy Hi! I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to get the backViewController description as a String? If so, you might consider to `println("backViewController is: \(backViewController.description)")`; this will give you a description like "UINavigationController: 0x7fcea1d286b0", which is not very clear but at least allows you to identify the object. As I said, I'm not sure of what you need exactly...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `navigationController` method to retrieve it. See [documentation on Apple's site](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewController).

> **navigationController** A parent or ancestor that is a navigation
>   controller. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UINavigationController
>   *navigationController
>
> *Discussion* Only returns a navigation controller if the view
>   controller is in its stack. This property is nil if a navigation
>   controller cannot be found.
>
> *Availability* Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Find the previous view controller is simple.

In your case, i.e., you are in C and you need B, `[self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject]` is what you want.

For A, since A is the root view controller, you can just replace `lastObject` with `firstObject` to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

Because dead horses enjoy being beaten :)

```
- (UIViewController *)previousViewController
{
    NSArray *vcStack = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    NSInteger selfIdx = [vcStack indexOfObject:self];
    if (vcStack.count < 2 || selfIdx == NSNotFound) { return nil; }
    return (UIViewController *)[vcStack objectAtIndex:selfIdx - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more succinct Swift impementation:

```
extension UIViewController {
    var previousViewController: UIViewController? {
        guard let nav = self.navigationController,
              let myIdx = nav.viewControllers.index(of: self) else {
            return nil
        }
        return myIdx == 0 ? nil : nav.viewControllers[myIdx-1]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation for Swift 2.2 - Add this in an `UIViewController` extension. Safe in the sense it will return `nil` if the viewcontroller is the rootvc or not in a navigationcontroller.

```
var previousViewController: UIViewController? {
  guard let viewControllers = navigationController?.viewControllers else {
    return nil
  }
  var previous: UIViewController?
  for vc in viewControllers{
    if vc == self {
      break
    }
    previous = vc
  }
  return previous
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Swift using guard.

```
extension UIViewController {

    func getPreviousViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        guard let _ = self.navigationController else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers else {
            return nil
        }

        guard viewControllers.count >= 2 else {
            return nil
        }        
        return viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My extension, swift 3

```
extension UIViewController {
    var previousViewController: UIViewController? {
        guard let controllers = navigationController?.viewControllers, controllers.count > 1 else { return nil }
        switch controllers.count {
        case 2: return controllers.first
        default: return controllers.dropLast(2).first
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**for swift 3** you can do this:

```
var backtoViewController:UIViewController!
for viewController in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)!.reversed() {
    if viewController is NameOfMyDestinationViewController {
            backtoViewController = viewController
    }
}
self.navigationController!.popToViewController(backtoViewController, animated: true)
```

You only need replace "NameOfMyDestinationViewController" by viewController that you want to return.