# How to get the previous viewcontroller that pushed my current view

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

The home page of my app has `UIButtons`, `btnIncome` and `btnExpense`. Pressing on this buttons pushes `IncomeVC` and `ExpenseVC` respectevely,which are two `UIViewControllers` with `UITabBar` added via xib. The tabBar have 4 items. Selecting on each tab item adds same four view controllers(which contains `UITableViews`) as the subview of `IncomeVC` and `ExpenseVC`,like for eg, DailyVC,WeeklyVC,MonthlyVC,YearlyVC.(ie,for Income ,there is daily,weekly etc and same for Expense) (I have done like that because the `IncomeVC` and `ExpenseVC` have a `UIButton` and a `UIView` which is common for all tabs).

So the problem is that, if click the `btnIncome` I have to populate those tableviews with the arrays related to Income and vice versa for Expense. How can I find from which viewController I selected the different tabs(I need to get it from the 4 Views I added as the subview of IncomeVC and ExpenseVC). Do I have to make 8 different views 4 each for Income and expense ?
Thanx.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the reason for needing access to the previous view controller is to know what data to get, I would suggest that you instead give the new view controller the data before you push it on the stack. Or at least enough data so that the view controller know how to get the right data, e.g. a enum or constant or something.

This could be done with a custom initializer, or a property.
Take a look at this blog post for an example: ["Passing Data Between View Controllers"](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/passing-data-between-view-controllers/)

If you are using a storyboard, you can use `prepareForSegue:sender` to pass the right data. A good tutorial on that can be found here: [Beginning Storyboards in iOS 5 Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2)

Answer (score 40):

In **Swift 3**,

```
if let navController = self.navigationController, navController.viewControllers.count >= 2 {
     let viewController = navController.viewControllers[navController.viewControllers.count - 2]
}
```

Answer (score 38):

You can get the previous viewController like following code,

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-2]);
```

This will displays the previous viewController name...

Comment: @Erik count property is always greater by 1 then the index so to get the UIViewController before the current UIViewController  you must subtract 2 from the count

Comment: Potential crash due to array out of bounds

Comment: I obviously know and that's the reason why I downvoted. You should fix your code or add the comment warning other people that your code is insecure. btw, I upvoted you answer for Swift 3

Answer (score 21):

In **Swift**:

```
let n: Int! = self.navigationController?.viewControllers?.count
let myUIViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[n-2] as! UIViewController
```

Comment: It's unsafe access directly n-2 because if you are the first VC you will have an error. Maybe you can use an previous validation.

Answer (score 16):

#### Swift 5.1

(Based on previous answers but simpler)

```
extension UINavigationController {
    var previousViewController: UIViewController? {
       viewControllers.count > 1 ? viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2] : nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 3**

Here is a mashup of the previous answers that can be put into an extension:

```
extension UIViewController{
   var previousViewController:UIViewController?{
        if let controllersOnNavStack = self.navigationController?.viewControllers, controllersOnNavStack.count >= 2 {
            let n = controllersOnNavStack.count
            return controllersOnNavStack[n - 2]
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

When fetching the `previousViewController` of a given view controller, call it VC1, in `viewWillDisappear`, VC1 is already popped of the Navigation Controller Stack. So in this scenario, the above code does not end up fetching the View controller directly above VC1(call it VC2), but the view controller above VC2 (if it exists).

To avoid this problem I just check if VC1 is still on the stack when `previousViewController` is requested. Here is the updated code:

```
extension UIViewController{
    var previousViewController:UIViewController?{
        if let controllersOnNavStack = self.navigationController?.viewControllers{
            let n = controllersOnNavStack.count
            //if self is still on Navigation stack
            if controllersOnNavStack.last === self, n > 1{
                return controllersOnNavStack[n - 2]
            }else if n > 0{
                return controllersOnNavStack[n - 1]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This code assumes that view controller you are sending the `previousViewController` message to will either be at the top of the navigation stack or not at all.

Comment: Is it possible to have a situation in which the view controller being viewed is not on the top of the navigation stack?

Answer (score 5):

```
UIViewController *previousViewController = [[[self navigationController]viewControllers] objectAtIndex:([viewControllers indexOfObject:self]-1)];
```

Where self will be current view controller.

Answer (score 4):

### `[viewControllers.count - 2]` approach is buggy

If stated view controller is **not last view controller** of the navigation stack,`[viewControllers.count - 2]` returns incorrect result.

New crash safe solution:

## Swift

```
extension UIViewController {

    var previousViewController: UIViewController? {
        guard 
            let viewControllers = navigationController?.viewControllers,
            let index = viewControllers.firstIndex(of: self),
            index > 0
        else { return nil }
        
        return viewControllers[index - 1]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Swift

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func getPreviousViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        let count = viewControllers.count
        guard count > 1 else { return nil }
        return viewControllers[count - 2]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly reuse the view controllers. I would suggest instead of pushing UIViewController (which contains UITabBar added from IB) when the button is pressed, you can push UITabBarController which contains 4 View Controllers (daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly).

You UITabBarController could have an enum property (Income and Expense) and this can be assigned when you push this UITabBarController based on the button pressed. From there, you can assign another enum property (Income and Expense) to the 4 UIViewControllers to show the correct type of data in each view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post: [How to identify previous view controller in navigation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005787/objective-c-how-to-identify-previous-view-controller-in-navigation-stack)
Tony is right, you can get the previous VC from the viewControllers array but at index n-2.