# How to open screen already in stack instead of creating new one in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, applet

I'm facing a problem that If a Screen (ViewController) is already in the stack than it can be opened again. Let V1 is a view controller. I go to v2 from V1 as V1->V2 and than V2->V3. Now I want to open V1 from V3. I am using NavigationViewController to open the screens as -

```
let help = V1(nibName : "V1" , bundle:  nil)
navViewcontroller?.navigationController?.pushViewController(help, animated: true)
```

this creates a new V1 Screen I am not able to use V1 already I stack.

Please answer how it is possible, Sorry for mistakes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the previous viewcontroller that pushed my current view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608536/how-to-get-the-previous-viewcontroller-that-pushed-my-current-view)

Comment: See this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273506/navigation-controller-loop/47278412#47278412

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you exactly know the index of the view controller in stack then you can simply use:

```
let viewController = navigationController?.viewControllers[index]
navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Otherwise you can travers your view controllers and find it:

```
for viewController in (navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
    if viewController is LoginMobileVC { // LoginMobileVC is your view controller class
        navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: how to get count of view controllers  using navigationController.. so that i can use for loop to find existing one

Comment: @SanjayMajoka use `let count = navigationController?.viewControllers.count`

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
if let navController = self.navigationController, let VC1 = navController.viewControllers.first {
     _ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(VC1 as! YourVC, animated: true)
}
```

or

```
self.navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

//**NOTE**: These will work if VC1 is the base navigation controller